# query/stored procedure which reads db records and transforms into different form?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have service, which sends info to the server for every 5min. I have below set of records in DB:

```
RecordId | sensorId | status | timestamp
       1 |        3 |   good | 07/31/2018 2:10:00.000
       2 |        3 |   good | 07/31/2018 2:15:00.000
       3 |        3 |   good | 07/31/2018 2:20:00.000
       4 |        3 |   good | 07/31/2018 2:25:00.000
       5 |        3 |   good | 07/31/2018 2:30:00.000
       6 |        3 |    bad | 07/31/2018 2:35:00.000
       7 |        3 |    bad | 07/31/2018 2:40:00.000
       8 |        3 |   good | 07/31/2018 2:45:00.000
       9 |        3 |    bad | 07/31/2018 2:50:00.000
```

Now I need to write a query/stored procedure which reads the above records and load the data as below format into another table

```
 id | sensorId | status | From                   | To
101 |         3|   good | 07/31/2018 2:10:00.000 | 07/31/2018 2:30:00.000
102 |         3|    bad | 07/31/2018 2:35:00.000 | 07/31/2018 2:40:00.000
103 |         3|   good | 07/31/2018 2:45:00.000 | 07/31/2018 2:50:00.000
104 |         3|    bad | 07/31/2018 2:50:00.000 | 07/31/2018 2:55:00.000
```

Can we transform the data from the given table to this above table? Please suggest approach/solution to transform the data?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a "gaps-and-islands" problem.  A relatively simple solution is to identify the "islands" of like statuses using the difference of `row_numbers()`.

```
select sensorid, status, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sensorid order by timestamp) as seqnum_s,
             row_number() over (partition by sensorid, status order by timestamp) as seqnum_ss
      from t
     ) t
group by sensorid, status, (seqnum_s - seqnum_ss);
```